# Finding $d^2z$, where $z=\arctan(x/y) + \sin (x/y)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative

I have to find $d^2z$ of the function
$$z=\arctan(x/y) + \sin (x/y)$$
So this means I wil have to find
$$dz = \frac{dz}{dx}dx +  \frac{dz}{dy}dy$$
then
$$(d^2)z = \left(d \frac{dz}{dx}\right)dx + \left(d \frac{dz}{dy}\right)dy$$
Is there any shorter way?

Comment: You can find some good starting points on how to format mathematics on the site [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020). [This AMS reference](ftp://ftp.ams.org/ams/doc/amsmath/short-math-guide.pdf) is very useful.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\par#1#2{\frac{\partial^{#2}z}{\partial #1^{#2}}}$There is no "shorter" way as computing the second partial derivatives and obtaining
$$ d^2 z = \par x2 dx\,dx + 2 \frac{\partial^2 z}{\partial x\partial y} dx\,dy + \par y2 dy\,dy $$